# Concatenate strings to specify field name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server but porting on MySQL so I need a solution for both ideally (but MySQL preferably)

I am trying to concatenate two field in order to specify the field name for the select statement.

Example table:

```
id     | name
1      | John
2      | Bob


SELECT id, 'na'+'me' as value FROM table WHERE 1=1
```

actual return (of course)

```
id     | value
1      | name
2      | name
```

expected return:

```
id     | value
1      | John
2      | Bob
```

I have no clue as to how to specify that the concatenate result is to be used as field name, and not as result.

Comment: Where do you specify your columns name? In application?

Comment: Bot wuite sure if I understand, but if you want your expected return result: SELECT id, [name] as value FROM table

Comment: How do you get 'na' and 'me' values?

Comment: sorry if I did not specify, 'na' and 'me' are an example, but the values aregenerated from code (delphi). in this case, the tables have an english and "foreign" fields for text, the foreign starts with "xx" so the table would have name and xxname as two columns. when the program is in english, I need to fetch the field name and in any other language, the field xxname.. hence the request to be able to concatenate two values in order to generate the field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused by your question but the query you need to get the `expected return` is simply:

```
SELECT id, name as value FROM Table
```

This will work in both mySQL and SQL Server

**UPDATE:**

It just occured to me that you might be talking about specifying which column to select using concatenated values.  To do this in SQL Server use dynamic SQL.  Example:

```
EXEC('SELECT id, ' + 'na' + 'me' + ' as value FROM table WHERE 1=1')
```

The above would be pointless if that's how you actually plan on using it.  If `na` and `me` are parameters or something this would make sense.  Be sure to read [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before using Dynamic SQL in SQL Server.

**MySQL Version:**

```
mysql> set @sql_text := 'SELECT id, ' + 'na' + 'me' + ' as value FROM table WHERE 1=1';

mysql> prepare stmt from 
    -> @sql_text

mysql> EXECUTE stmt
```

Lifted from [here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).

Comment: No, this is just SQL Server.  Trying to come up with the mySQL equivalent

Comment: Updated with the MySQL Version

Comment: @Abe After preparation you need to execute :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to dynamically generate SQL with SQL? If so, use your SQL to generate a valid SQL command and then use the EXEC command on it. ([MSDN documentation for T-SQL EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx))

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT id, ' + 'na' + 'me' + ' as value FROM table WHERE 1=1'
EXEC (@SQL);
```

If you need to generate from data, something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT id, ' + field1 + field2 + ' as value FROM table WHERE 1=1' FROM sometable WHERE 1=1
EXEC (@SQL);
```

This is generally discouraged for security. Depending on how you're getting the data to generate the SQL it could allow for SQL injection attacks. Use with caution.